# How to copy, move, and delete shapes in Krita

Tags: krita

I want to make a "drawing" of ellipses.  Doing it by hand is far beyond my ability so I'll use a program.  I chose Krita at random.  I've spent an hour reading manuals and watching tutorials and am none the wiser.

I need to be able to

1. copy and paste the shapes.
2. move the shapes around
3. select and delete shapes I don't want.

When I try to copy and paste a shape there is no apparent result.

It would be nice to be able to change the color of a shape but I can live without it.

If some other program is better I'll use that.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Although Krita is very good for digital painting, it's not the best software for creating designs based on vector shapes, even though it has basic vector capabilities. If you find yourself doing work like this often, it might be a good idea to take a look at Inkscape which is a free and Open Source vector image editor.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

> When I try to copy and paste a shape there is no apparent result.

You are working in the default type of layer, the “Paint Layer”. For manipulating shapes it is much more comfortable to work in a **vector layer**.
Create it:

- From the menu select   *Setting → Dockers → Layers*
  to show the Layers docker, then in its bottom part

  [image]

  click on the **arrow** just next to “+”: [image].
- From the pop-up menu select *“Vector Layer”*. The new vector layer becomes your current layer.
- Create some shape(s) in it.

1. **Copy and paste shapes:**

   1. Select the shape by selecting the *“Select Shapes Tool”* [image] (the first tool in the toolbox), and then clicking on the desired shape.
      You will see handles around it and in the center of it.

      [image]
   2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it.
   3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste it.

      The pasted shape will appear over the original, slightly shifted to the right and to the down.
      [image]
   4. You may move the pasted shape by dragging it with the mouse, *out of its handles* (so the cursor will have the *four-arrows shape*).

      [image]
2. **Move the shape around:**

   1. Select it as in the previous point.
   2. Drag it by the mouse (as in the previous point).
3. **Delete the shape:**

   1. Select it  as in the previous points.
   2. Press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.
4. **Change the color of your shape:**

   1. Select it as in the previous points.
   2. You will need the Tool Options docker:   *Setting → Dockers → Tool Options*.

      [image]
   3. In the top part of 3 buttons [image] click on the *middle* button [image].
   4. You will see the current color of your shape in the form of a band:

      [image]
   5. Click directly on that band. The color palette and the color picker pop up:

      [image]
   6. Select the desired color, and you will immediately see the result:
      [image]